# How do I store an array of values using GORM + Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have tried using the docs [here](https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html) describing Many-to-Many relationships, but when I exactly copy their example, I get an error.

Here is a slimmed-down version of the code (which requires Postgres to be running locally on port 5432):

`main.go`

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    Languages []Language `gorm:"many2many:user_languages;"`
}

type Language struct {
    gorm.Model
    Name string
}

func main() {
    dsn := "host=localhost user=postgres password=asdf dbname=postgres port=5432"
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    check("connect to db", err)

    err = db.AutoMigrate(&User{}, &Language{})
    check("migrate models", err)
}

func check(task string, err error) {
    if err != nil {
        panic(fmt.Sprintf("error during %v: %v", task, err.Error()))
    }
}
```

`go.mod`

```
module testpostgres

go 1.21.1

require (
    gorm.io/driver/postgres v1.5.2
    gorm.io/gorm v1.25.4
)

// ** + indirect requirements ** //
```

When I run main.go I get this:

```
go/src/testpostgres/main.go:25 ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "users" (SQLSTATE 42830)
[4.951ms] [rows:0] CREATE TABLE "user_languages" ("user_id" bigint,"language_id" bigint,PRIMARY KEY ("user_id","language_id"),CONSTRAINT "fk_user_languages_user" FOREIGN KEY ("user_id") REFERENCES "users"("id"),CONSTRAINT "fk_user_languages_language" FOREIGN KEY ("language_id") REFERENCES "languages"("id"))
panic: error while trying to migrate models: ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "users" (SQLSTATE 42830)
```

How would I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

As the error message suggests, you are missing a unique constraint on the `users` table under the `id` column: `ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "users"`

Without such a unique constraint, when you join the `users` table with the `user_languages` table, Postgres won't know which row of the `users` table to link with.

Therefore, you'll need to either add a unique constraint or primary key (if one doesn't already exist):

```
ALTER TABLE "users" ADD PRIMARY KEY (id);
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE "users" ADD CONSTRAINT users_id_uniq UNIQUE (id);
```

If my hunch is correct, you'll probably need to do the same thing on the `languages` table as well